# How source port field in firewall rule is used

Tags: firewalls, tcp

Some firewalls (like the first figure in 13.1.4 in http://doc.m0n0.ch/handbook/examples.html) allow user to specify source port in a firewall rules. But in a TCP connection, the source port is randomly selected from 1024 - MAX. So my question is, why we need to have a source port field in a firewall rule? And we can see that some other firewalls do not provide a source port field in their rule format (e.g. http://www.fwbuilder.org/4.0/docs/users_guide5/global-policy.shtml)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source port is *usually* randomly selected, however applications do have the option to specify a source port. It's within the realm of possibility that someone would want to filter on a specific source port, although it is extremely rare.

In the past I've seen source port rules used in order to permit audio and video streaming when the firewall's H.323 detection was not automatically opening the ports, and that feature was tremendously useful in setting up a workaround.

Answer (score 3):

One example where source port with TCP is necessary is active ftp. In this case the client (inside the firewall) listens on a kind of random port on the client for the data connection and notifies the server about this addr+port using the PORT command. The server then connects **from** port 20 - and this is the only restriction you can set if you need to allow active ftp.

Comment: Thank you! Your example is very interesting! A good introduction to active FTP: http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html#active

Answer (score 1):

You mention that TCP requests are (often) from randomized ports, but what about RESPONSES? An HTTP request might come from a random source port, but the reply will come from a known source port (80/443/ etc.). Sometimes you want control over the responses as well as incoming requests.

Comment: Yes. This is a good point. But I am thinking that you can always achieve your goal by only focusing on requests.

Comment: If you allow in one way you also allow in the other way so you get response. With firewall that keep state can you really do kind of one way HTTP ?